# No module named django

Tags: python, django

When running:

```
(DjangoProject) PS C:\Users\Travinns\Documents\GitHub\HBH site> django-admin.py startproject HBHsite
```

I get the error:

`from django.core import management ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'`

I followed [this](http://taswar.zeytinsoft.com/visual-studio-code-with-python-django/) guide and it goes wrong at the 'Lets now create a our first Django project.' step.

I already searched around and if I run the following:

```
python -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"
```

I get:

`C:\Users\Travinns\Envs\DjangoProject\Scripts\python35.zip
C:\Users\Travinns\Envs\DjangoProject\DLLs
C:\Users\Travinns\Envs\DjangoProject\lib
C:\Users\Travinns\Envs\DjangoProject\Scripts
c:\users\travinns\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\Lib
c:\users\travinns\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\DLLs
C:\Users\Travinns\Envs\DjangoProject
C:\Users\Travinns\Envs\DjangoProject\lib\site-packages
C:\Users\Travinns\Documents\GitHub\HBH site`

Django is in C:\Users\Travinns\Envs\DjangoProject\lib\site-packages so this should work.

If I run:

```
Python
import django
django
```

I get:

```
<module 'django' from 'C:\\Users\\Travinns\\Envs\\DjangoProject\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\__init__.py'>
```

Which confirms my statement. What am I missing?

Extra info: 
I am running on Windows.

Comment: This basically means `django` is not found, can you do `pip install django` and then check if `python -c import django;print(django.get_version())` works without throwing an error.

Comment: It _used_ to be hosted [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) which would fix the problem straight away. The fact that he dropped it from his compiled binaries makes me wonder about Windows compatibility. I had a copy of the wheel in my last company and had to distribute that for Windows but unfortunately I can't access it now.

Comment: Aha, it's back! Go to https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and search "django". Download `Django‑1.11.7‑py2.py3‑none‑any.whl`, open a `cmd` window in your downloads folder (hold shift and right click, then "open command prompt here") then do `pip install Django‑1.11.7‑py2.py3‑none‑any.whl`.

Comment: @roganjosh I get the following error if I try this:



`M:\Downloads>pip install Django-1.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement 'Django\u20111.11.7\u2011py2.py3\u2011none\u2011any.whl' looks like
a filename, but the file does not exist
Django\u20111.11.7\u2011py2.py3\u2011none\u2011any.whl is not a valid wheel file
name.`

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla If I first run the command `Python` and then `-c import django;print(django.get_version())` I get `1.11.17` as response.

Comment: Now can you run `django-admin.py startproject HBHsite` since you seem to be having django installed correctly.

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla Hmm not yet. It gives a syntax error which is weird. SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> django-admin.py startproject HBHsite
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    django-admin.py startproject HBHsite
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax